# Can SSMS indent xml when pasting into Editor?

Tags: sql, xml, ssms, sql-server-2014

Does SSMS - SQL Server 2014 have an option to automatically indent XML text?

I save XML text in a column (`nvarchar(max)`) to analyze the input of an application.

Usually the result of my queries are set to grid and I copy and paste the result into the query editor to read it.

This is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><farm-confirm source="orders.company.com"><Detail><item_keyid>3207890</item_keyid><item_code>50002035</item_code></Detail></farm-confirm>
```

This is what I would like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<farm-confirm source="orders.company.com">
    <Detail>
        <item_keyid>3207890</item_keyid>
        <item_code>50002035</item_code>
    </Detail>
</farm-confirm>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you store your XML as type `XML` ??

Comment: I am not sure why I chose to save it to nvarchar at that time (2 years ago). Maybe it was because not all of the input comes in well formed xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the XML is well formed, the easies was to do this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=N'Put your XML here';
SELECT @xml;
```

(Output to Grid-View)

And now just click on the XML. The XML-Viewer will present it formatted and indented.

Or take one of the free online XML prettyzizers.

Just google for `online pretty xml formatter`

#### update

If you get the XML (which is - in your case - a string actually) from a query, you might just wrap the column with `CAST(MyColumn AS XML)`. This will offer you the XML-Viewer immediately...